# Confusion in C++ constructor

Tags: c++, class, oop, object, constructor

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Obj {
public:
    Obj(){cout <<"create obj" << endl;}
    Obj(const Obj& other){cout<<"copy create obj"<<endl;}
    ~Obj(){cout<<"destructed obj"<<endl;}
};

int main() {
    Obj(Obj((Obj())));
    cout<<"---- exit main ----"<<endl;
}
```

I have no idea why this program only prints out 1 create obj and 1 destructed obj. Help.

Comment: Just for fun try this instead: `Obj{Obj{{Obj{}}}}; `

Comment: Oh! c++ compiler does not optimise this format? why???

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because of Copy Elision. Read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953127/what-are-copy-elision-and-return-value-optimization). Your compiler understands, that it can avoid copying the object around, and just creates one object.

Comment: Oh! Thank you very much! Just hard to imagine what c++ compiler does under the hood.

Comment: Another mini question: c++ compiler does not optimise this format, like Obj{Obj{{Obj{}}}}, why???

Comment: @chenyuandong it does for me, under GCC 8.